# Why would i get the below error(java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError) while running app authenticity in Android

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server, worklight-server

I created an android app and I have put a code for app authenticity in it .
I followed the below URLs to Implement it.

[application-authenticity-protection](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/authentication-security/application-authenticity-protection/)

[application-authenticity-protection-native-android-applications](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/authentication-security/application-authenticity-protection/application-authenticity-protection-native-android-applications/)

I am getting an error while testing it.
Can some body tell me when would we get the below error.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-3-thread-1
    Process: com.mtb.mbk_vpn, PID: 10084
        java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mtb.mbk_vpn-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.mtb.mbk_vpn-1/lib/x86, /data/app/com.mtb.mbk_vpn-1/base.apk!/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libauthjni.so"
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:367)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)
        at com.worklight.common.security.AppAuthenticityToken.<init>(AppAuthenticityToken.java:30)
        at com.worklight.wlclient.challengehandler.AuthenticityChallengeHandler.handleChallenge(AuthenticityChallengeHandler.java:81)
        at com.worklight.wlclient.challengehandler.AuthenticityChallengeHandler.handleChallenge(AuthenticityChallengeHandler.java:32)
        at com.worklight.wlclient.api.challengehandler.BaseChallengeHandler.startHandleChallenge(BaseChallengeHandler.java:71)
        at com.worklight.wlclient.WLRequest.checkResponseForChallenges(WLRequest.java:626)
        at com.worklight.wlclient.WLRequest.requestFinished(WLRequest.java:292)
        at com.worklight.wlclient.WLRequestSender.run(WLRequestSender.java:52)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> couldn't find "libauthjni.so" at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary

Looks to me like you did not copy all required SDK files from the NativeAPI you've created via CLI/Studio, into your native project in Android Studio/Eclipse.

Make sure you've done that.

Comment: Can you tell me if I need to add x86,mips64,armeabi,armeabi-v7a files to the android native project in Android studio.

Comment: You need those depending on the device hardware you're planning on supporting. Since android devices are spread across various hardware architectures, you may want all of them.

Comment: Do I need to put them in the lib folder of android project or should I put them under root directory of android project

Comment: In the lib folder.

Comment: Ok Idan, Will try it.